# Best books on finite group extensions

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-extensions

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the classification problem for finite groups and in particular the extension problem. I'm looking for some advanced books on the theory of finite group extensions which extensively and deeply covers the topic. Maybe an all-in-one book doesn't exist, in case I'd like also suggestions on books covering related and more specific topics such as Shur's multiplier and Group cohomology.

Comment: What about my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_76_coho.pdf), in particular  Chapter $2$ , and Chapter $3$, section $3.5$? This includes the work of Zassenhaus on factor systems, i.e., for arbitrary group extensions (while the second cohomology only classifies abelian extensions). And group cohomology is studied in detail, also Schur and Zassenhaus theorems.

Comment: Most introductory books on group theory will cover this. Good ones are Rotman, "An introduction to the theory of groups", Chapter 7 and Robinson, "A course in the theory of groups", Chapter 11.